# how to resolve warning ''using a subshell to avoid having to cd back'

Tags: bash, dockerfile, cd, subshell

The folder structure like this:

```
folder_01
├── folder_02├──Dockerfile_02
├── folder_03├──Dockerfile_03 & example.sh
```

In the example.sh script, I want to use `cd` to navigate back to `folder_02` and use the dockerfile_02 to build an image and then navigate back to the current dir (which is `folder_03`)
Here's what I tried:

```
cd ..
cd ./folder_02
docker build . -t image_name

cd ..
cd ./folder_03
```

In intelliJ, it gave me warning `using a subshell to avoid having to cd back`, I read some documentation about it but haven't got a solution, can someone help me?

Comment: Did you ask the same question twice? [how to resolve warning ''using a subshell to avoid having to cd back'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61956289/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks for letting me know, must be the bad network connection and I submitted twice accidentally. I've deleted the other one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can invoke the commands in a subshell `(...)`:

```
(
   cd ./folder_02
   docker build . -t image_name
)
(
   cd ./folder_03
   something else
)
```

In scripts that I want to preserve environment I use `pushd`+`popd`.

```
pushd ./folder_02 >/dev/null
docker build . -t image_name
popd >/dev/null

pushd ./folder_03 >/dev/null
something soemthing
popd >/dev/null
```

Comment: As per the question post, the PWD is folder_03. I supppose this answer has to be changed for that.

Comment: i know how `pushed`, `popd` and `dir` works, but what do you mean in to preserve the environment?

Comment: `a=1; ( a=2; ); echo "$a"`  will print `1`, because changes in subshell are not visible in parent shell. By "preserve environment" I meant that the environment of the `(...)` part is lost, and I want to keep using it in the script. Well, it's not the best term...

Comment: Note that `pushd` and `popd` are bash extensions, but `(cd dir; command)` is portable POSIX shell syntax.  In a Docker context this may make a difference, where lighter-weight Alpine-based images may not have bash available.

Answer (score 1):

you can use subshell `(...)` like what @KamilCuk said

```
(cd ../folder_02 && docker build . -t image_name )
(cd ../folder_03 && something else)
```

or

```
(cd ../folder_02; docker build . -t image_name )
(cd ../folder_03; something else)
```

Since with Docker, you can use the -f argument to select the Dockerfile to use :

```
docker build -t path/yourproject -f dockerfiles/myownDocker.docker .
```